# NSDatePicker with date in yy to yyyy format

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdatepicker

I have as `NSDatePicker`, where I enter 0023 and I expect it to change it to `2023`. My logic is to convert the `yy` to `yyyy` based on +-50 years.

But the default behavior of `NSDatePicker` changes it to `0023` etc.

What I need to do to show in `yyyy` format with nearest 50 years range.

Is there any way to do it through Interface Builder or through codes.

Your help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

It does not "change" `0023` to `0023`, it *leaves* it at `0023`, which is correct the correct behaviour. You'd need to manually check and fix this yourself. Maybe like (untested):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar
    components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit 
    fromDate:myPossiblyIncorrectDate
];
NSDate *correctedDate;

if ([components year] < 100) {
    NSUInteger currentYearLastDigits = 13; // Insert logic to get current year here.
    NSUInteger yearLastDigits = [components year];

    if (yearLastDigits > currentYearLastDigits) {
       [components setYear:1900 + yearLastDigits];
    } else {
       [components setYear:2000 + yearLastDigits];
    }

    correctedDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
} else {
    correctedDate = myPossiblyIncorrectDate;
}
```

Depending on how exact you need this to be, you might want to get/set more components. See the [NSCalendar constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-CJBJEIAF).

But it would be better to catch the wrong year number *before* the number is even interpreted as year number since the date might be invalid otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i tried above code with few changes it worked fine. But I needed to use above in an action button, is there any way to execute the above as soon as textDidEndEditing... kind of delegate?

Comment: @Kaushik Don't know how to right now. Please ask a new question regarding that (but search StackOverflow first, I'm sure you can find a similar question to the editing problem).